# Build an App for a Wordpress site. Is PhoneGap the solution?

Tags: wordpress, cordova

I have a few Wordpress sites and I would like to create apps (IOS and Android) for all of them. I did some research and found that PhoneGap (or similar products) appears to be the solution.

The App will simply get information from existing Wordpress site. I do not plan to add login/edit/post features to the app at this time. My sites have both Pages and Posts. Does that matter?

Is there any better solution than PhoneGap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two current big multi-platform solutions for apps are PhoneGap and Titanium. PhoneGap is less work, but Titanium has better performance and uses the platform default UI. Since you aren't building an advanced app, just reading JSON feeds, PhoneGap should work great for you.

It does not matter that you have both pages and posts. You will need to use a JSON API in order to get the data from WordPress. There are a couple plugins that do this and they are working on adding a JSON api to core right now. Until the core API is done, I would recommend using the WordPress.com JSON API that's included with the JetPack plugin since its made by Automattic and it has [great documentation](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/). If you go this route, you can also fairly easily add login/editing/posting later on with [OAUTH2](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/).

Answer (score 2):

You should also check out [Steroids.js](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids), which builds on top of PhoneGap and adds features like real-time updates to devices without compiling, native UI elements etc.